# How to do Linux as a guest on MacOS X using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Could someone please explain to me how to create a linux guest on OS X host?
When I create a VM (Ununtu) after start up it just gives some error messages and leave the VM.

Thanks
Artimess

Comment: would probably help to post the error messages

Comment: definitely. screenshot would be best (Command+Shift+4 then Space bar when focused on the VM's window)

Comment: need more info if you want a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Did you download an ISO to install? Typically download a CD-ROM image of the distro you want, then you mount the CD via the Storage tab, and finally boot the VM. Then just install it.

Comment: The installation goes fine, but when I run VM VirtalBox exits!

Comment: Did you try restarting it?